# Как адаптировать кнопки управления на андроид?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Вот сообственно сам код, который работает по типу "Нажимаешь W,S - куб двигается по оси x", "Нажимаешь A,D - куб двигается по оси z". [image: Вставьте сюда описание изображения]  Как адаптировать мой код ниже, под кнопки-стрелки? Помогите, пожалуйста, пролистал весь интернет - не нашёл решения своей проблемы.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GreenCube : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] KeyCode keyOne; // задаю в инспекторе на какую клавишу на клавиатуре будет управляться куб
    [SerializeField] KeyCode keyTwo; // задаю в инспекторе на какую клавишу на клавиатуре будет управляться куб
    [SerializeField] moveDirection // задаю в инспекторе направление и скорость

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(keyOne))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += moveDirection;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(keyTwo))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity -= moveDirection;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (this.CompareTag("Player") && other.CompareTag("Finish"))
        {
            UnLockLevel();
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        }
    }

    public void UnLockLevel()
    {
        int currentLevel = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

        if (currentLevel >= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levels"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levels", currentLevel + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать флаги которые будут устанавливаться при нажатии и отпускании стрелочек. Работает есть у стрелочек есть Box Collider 2D. Пример:

```
bool isRight;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isRight)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    isRight = true;
}

private void OnMouseUp()
{
    isRight = false;
}
```

Comment: В onclick кнопках выбрал public class bool enabled. Не работает

Comment: UI.Button.OnClick выполняется аналогично событию OnMouseDown. На кнопку тогда лучше добавить Add Component ->Event -> Event Trigger, добавить 2 события PointerDown и PointerUp, и использовать в место OnClick, которые будут устанавливать флаг или убирать. Чтобы установить флаг нужно обратиться к объекту GameObject у которого весит компонент GreenCube, получить компонент GetComponent<GreenCube>() и вызвать функцию для установки флага к примеру SetMoveRight(true/false).